# Do we have to install dependencies every time we branch out from master to fix an issue?

Tags: git, workflow

Say if i have a bug to fix on repository. By best practice, I need to create a new branch using version control to fix it.

But if I create a new branch, I need to install back all the dependencies like grunt/elixir every time.

Is there any better workflow?

Answer (score 3):

Git allows you to *version* your code. It doesn't handle dependencies.

In other words, the plugins/frameworks/tools you have installed (and their versions) are totally independent of the branch you are on.

**Example** : you are using NodeJs and `package.json`. As long as you don't change that file, you don't need to install new dependencies when you switch branches. However, if you add/edit dependencies in `package.json`, you would need to run `npm install` everytime you checkout on another branch.